# Mount an ISO in Elementary 5.1.3

Tags: mount

How do I mount an ISO? I tried 'mount' with the 'loop' option and get a 'failed to setup loop device' message. I've read elsewhere of installing gnome-disk-utilities or another software but am not sure how I go about installing them. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks,

Srini

Comment: can you provide the exact command you are typing please?

Comment: sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 "~/Downloads/my.iso" /media/iso. I had created the "iso" folder in /media previously.

Answer (score 1):

I guess "sudo apt install furiusisomount" did the job.